# Difference in garbage collector behavior on Android device versus the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, garbage-collection

I'm testing my application's memory usage on the emulator. And the problem is that on the emulator the app heap is just growing and growing, just a little bit of resources are freed. And if no collections are made it will cause an OutOfMemory exception on big resolution screens.

I downloaded the Sony SDK and there is an emulator configuration for the Xperia Z that has 1080x1920 resolution and the default heap is 64MB. I think it's a small heap size for that resolution because my app uses 40MB only starting up. However on my phone it's using 15MB of 64MB (res. 540x960).
 So this quite small heap size (might not be real?) + GC behavior is causing OutOfMemory quite fast.

On a real device (I've tested only on mine), GC is working very nicely, it's freeing resources that are no longer used, but I really cannot predict if that will work on other phones.

Should I ignore how GC is working on my emulator or might it be my app's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Growing heap on emulator indicates that at some point you have memory leak.

They are very common when you send intents between different applications ( e.g select image from gallery) . Most of device can handle such leaks with no problem.

Another reason for heap to grow up: inefficient memory operations. That means at some time you are asking to much memmory ( e.g you selected 5M image from gallery, created inpuststream for it and keep in memory as bitmap, so you asking 15+M emulator will show just hight heap grow, but most of devices will show error).

If you see heap grows - analyse your memory usage and detect leaks. [Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)
If you dont detect anything strange you can almost safely ignore heap warning.

Note: heap show supplied space, not used.